Moveit collision detection not working with stl mesh object
I've succesfully added two objects for testing. One of them is a primitive box and the other is a mesh object imported from an stl file. I can visualize them in Rviz and when I move into the objects with the interactive markers of motion planning display I can see the collision.
However, my goal is to check if there is a collision in the program. I set the robot_state to a collision position and when I use
planningSceneMonitorPtr->getPlanningScene()->checkCollision(creq, cres, *robot_state);
the program returns true for the primitive box but not for the mesh object. Why doesn't it work with the mesh object?
I use ROS 2 / humble
Edit: Apparently I needed to update planning scene monitor once the mesh object was added to planning scene. It worked after adding the following line.
planningSceneMonitorPtr->requestPlanningSceneState();
